# Angular upgrade guide. (SystemJS) Unexpected token <

Tags: angularjs, angular, upgrade, systemjs

everyone.
I'm trying to upgrade big appliction which was written on angular 1 to angular 2. As first step it try to create hybrid angular 1/2 appliction using [official guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#phonecat-upgrade-tutorial).

When all instructions was finished I get a error

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: (SystemJS) Unexpected token <
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:8000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:242:26)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:8000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:113:43)
    at http://localhost:8000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:535:57
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:8000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:275:35)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:8000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:8000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:433:35)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:8000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:349:25)
Evaluating http://localhost:8000/app
Error loading http://localhost:8000/app ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
```

my `systemjs.config.js`

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': '/node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: '/app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

my dependencies in `package.config`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.4.0",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
```

can someone help me with this?

Comment: is there any api request in your code? Look at the network tab to check if the api request is failing. I mostly get this error during development when the api is not sending the valid data.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The error appers when `zone.js` response `http://localhost:8000/app`. The server returns folder structure. But I don`t know how to fix it.

Comment: So, could you add the response and the what is the expected response and other related stuffs to the api request?

Comment: Request sen by `zone.js` library, and problem that I don't now what expected response. I think that it is wrong url, because it is a single page app without server side. The response from `url` is

`<html>
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
     <title>Index of /app/</title>
   </head>
   <body>
 <h1>Index of /app/</h1>
 <table><tr><td><code>(drwxr-xr-x)</code></td><td style="text-align: right; padding-left: 1em"><code></code></td><td style="padding-left: 1em"><a href="/app/../">.....`

Comment: It looks like your server is sending you the index page as response. `<h1>Index of /app/</h1>`. I could see that you must have returned the view as the response from your laravel controller. So, you should send some data as the response and not the view. I suppose you are using laravel as your backend. I might be wrong though.

Comment: There is no backend, it is just static http server. You can see `start` script in [github](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/blob/master/package.json)

Comment: Any updates of this, facing the same issue, upgrading from angularjs 1 to angular 5?

Comment: Same here any updates on this??

Comment: unfortunately no, I have't worked on this issue.

Comment: Any Update on this?

Answer (score 0):

You should fix that by adding the main entry point for app.

```
packages: {
  app: {
    main: 'main.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
  },
  rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the `app/main.js` file is missing.

The `http-server` is returning HTML equivalent to `index.html` because there is no file to return. This is not the UMD module that `zone.js` expects, so we are getting a parsing error.

You will need to ignore this error once and proceed with the official guide.